# NSButton programmatically Push on Push off Type

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I am creating Buttons in Swift MacOS programmatically the following way:

```
        let feld = NSButton()
        feld.frame = CGRect(x: 900+30*h, y: 20, width: 22, height: 22)
        feld.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Mulleimer"))
        feld.target = self
        feld.action = #selector(ButtonTest)
        self.view.addSubview(feld)
```

Now I want to change the style of the button to "Push on Push off".
I tried stuff like this:

```
feld.setButtonType(NSButton.???)
```

It just never works. I know the answer should be at:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton/1524983-setbuttontype

But dont know, I just dont understand how to transform this to working code. May anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use code completion.

Type `setButtonType(` and the dot and you will see

[image]

so it's simply

```
feld.setButtonType(.pushOnPushOff)
```

PS: Did you import `AppKit`?